# C# - Contextmenu bug with SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I use a contextmenu on a pictureEdit (Devexpress) so when user right clicks and select the menu item it should save the file. But the context menu is still showing when the saveDialog windows is open.

How do I remove that bug?

```
    private void InitializeContextMenu()
    {
        ui_PictureEdit.Properties.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();

        var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        menu.Items.Add("Save image");
        menu.ItemClicked += ContextMenu_SaveImageClicked;
        menu.Show();

        ui_PictureEdit.Properties.ContextMenuStrip = menu;
    }



        using (var dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            dialog.DefaultExt = "*.png";
            dialog.Filter = "Image files (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ui_PictureEdit.Image.Save(dialog.FileName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding menu.Hide(); in the beginning of the ContextMenu_SaveImageClicked event?

Comment: Have you tried contextMenuStrip.Enabled = false in if block?

Comment: menu.Hide() did work! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can close the question:

Move the `menu` object to a scope where it's accessible by the ContextMenu_SaveImageClicked handler, then include this line in the handler:

```
menu.Hide();
```

To elaborate a bit, the context menu is a top-level window which will appear over any other window that isn't also top-level, including the file dialog. And clicking an item doesn't automatically hide the context menu, at least not before the event handler is executed, which is why you need to do it manually before popping up the dialog.